# Schtasks /create /sc onlogon gives me an error

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to create a task that starts up when the user logs on.

I get the following ERROR when creating this task:

```
schtasks /create /sc ONLOGON /tn ComputerMonitor_LoginCheck /tr c:\users\jdl\ComputerMonitor.bat

ERROR: Access is denied.
```

---

**** This works for a task to kick off every minute: (meaning I am able to create tasks on the computer)

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn ComputerMonitor_Check1Minute /tr c:\users\jdl\ComputerMonitor.bat

SUCCESS: The scheduled task "ComputerMonitor_Check1Minute" has successfully been created.
```

---

when I try to add a machine: ERROR:

```
schtasks /create /s LAPTOP-N008KAV3 /u jdl /sc ONLOGON /tn ComputerMonitor_LoginCheck /tr c:\users\jdl\ComputerMonitor.bat
Please enter the run as password for jdl: ********

ERROR: User credentials are not allowed on the local machine.
```

---

This fails too:

```
schtasks /create /sc ONLOGON /tn ComputerMonitor_LoginCheck /tr c:\users\jdl\ComputerMonitor.bat /ru jdl
ERROR: Access is denied.
```

---

Why is my question being being knocked?
I have searched and tried others as you see!